# Scale iframe to fit available space while keeping aspect ratio with pure CSS?

Tags: css, iframe, responsive-design, aspect-ratio

I want to achieve behaviour like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gke2mtbe/), but with `iframe` instead of `img`.

What I've tried:

- Trick with `img` and `max-width: 100%`, `max-height: 100%` works only for images, not for iframes.
- Trick with `padding-bottom` in percents on parent div only sets height by known width, so it's not what I want.

I've also thought about using SVG `foreignObject`, because AFAIK SVG resizes the same way as `img` does, but this tag seems unsupported by IE.

Is there any other solution I'm missing, or it's impossible without js?

Comment: you mean you need like image in same as in iframe?

Comment: What is so cool in your example? https://jsfiddle.net/gke2mtbe/1/

Comment: https://fettblog.eu/blog/2013/06/16/preserving-aspect-ratio-for-embedded-iframes/